# UISearchBar for Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

> How to deal `UISearchBar` with Core Data in Swift 3? I found a
>   tutorial on Google but many things doesn't work in new version of
>   Swift.

Comment: At least tell what you tried and what did not work, plus what you are trying to achieve. What kind of answers are you expecting with such a vague question? Better still link that tutorial you mention to make things more relevant.

Comment: I'm looking for a good tutorial in UISearchBar using Swift 3

Comment: There is no guarantee that a tutorials are always kept up to date. My best advise to you is to learn the logic from those you already found, then ask questions here about the parts that did not work as it should in the tutorial. That way the answers you get will be more helpful.

Comment: Use a UISearchController instead. It's rather than the UISearchBar. You can create a search machine using a NSPredicate.

Answer (score 0):

you have to first fetch all the core data that you have saved using the fetch function and then you can use the searchBar delegate to filter your results using the filter function.

```
do {
        let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = YourEntityName.fetchRequest()



        let Array = try returnContext().fetch(fetchReq)

        for entity in Array {

            let Entity: Array = entity as! YourEntityName

                let filter = Entity.filter({ (item: ContactData) -> Bool in                     

                    //Use range(of:) function to filter your result with the searched result and return true or false accordingly.
                    let str = name.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased())
                    return str != nil ? true : false
                })
                if filter.count > 0 {

                   //Use this block to create a temporary data model and then use tableView.reloadData() to reload your table with the searched results. This block is not necessary. Its usability depends on your source code.

                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("ERROR")
    }
```